# How to add an input to a group in the obs web socket

Tags: python, websocket, obs

Obs WebSocket docs define that groups in OBS are actually scenes, but renamed and modified. In obs-web sockets, we treat them as scenes where we can.

```
import obsws_python as obs


cl = obs.ReqClient(host='localhost', port=4444, password='password', timeout=3)


cl.create_input("Group","media","ffmpeg_source", {}, True)
```

but when I try to add an input to a specified group it gives me this error:

```
obsws_python.error.OBSSDKRequestError: Request CreateInput returned code 602. With the message: The specified source is not a scene. (Is group)
```

How to add an input to a specific group?